# Can't Install Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: system-installation

I've been trying to install Ubuntu on a Samsung S3520 with an 'Intel HD Graphic Family' card. I've tried with 12.04 versions and the latest 13.04 version. When I get to the boot menu to start installing it I click install and nothing happens. I also tried the YUMI boot and it doesn't work.

Any suggestions? Please note, I'm very new to this.. I just want to exit Windows forever
.

Comment: Can you run the live environment of Ubuntu? If yes, try to install from there.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use your Live-DVD or Live-USB and click on <kbd>Try Ubuntu</kbd>
This will allow you to see if Ubuntu runs well on your PC

[image]

Then, from there, install Ubuntu

[image]

Well everything is explained [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install)